# Php error handling

Tags: php, error-handling

I have now a function like this

```
function checkInput($content, $emptyMessage = ""){
    if(isset($content)){ 
       return sanitize($content);
    }else{
       return $emptyMessage;
    }
 }
```

And I use it like this:

```
/* First get all data out of key and put it in array*/

//now check the input if user has set certain fields
$email = checkInput($user["email"],"No email address given");

echo $email;
```

Now I get:     Uncaught ErrorOrWarningException.
I can think of two solutions:

Turning off errors > dont like that one.

Do manually for every field like

```
if(isset($user["email"])){ 
     $email = sanitize($user["email"]);
}else{
     $email =  "No email address given";
}
echo $email;
```

That sucks for readibility.
Another way would be to try / catch but thats almost the same length to type

Comment: Why write your own validation logic when you can use something like `filter_var()` and just worry about passing in the correct options?

Comment: I am not sure but I think the problem with your function, the second argument is optional, so it may not be set at all, then you try to return a variable may or may not set. So I suggest to make your second argument not optional and see what happen then.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When declaring a function with parameters, the parameter will always *be set* inside the function.

```
function checkInput($content, $emptyMessage = "") {
    // $content is always "set" here, no need for isset()
```

You're getting a warning if you're trying to access a non-existent variable here:

```
checkInput($user["email"], "No email address given");
  //       ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  // if 'email' is not set, a warning is thrown here
```

You'll always need to make sure the `"email"` key is set before trying to pass its value into a function.

Having said that, that's probably not the cause of your `ErrorOrWarningException`. I have no idea where that comes from, it's not standard PHP. I suppose your `sanitize` function is throwing it. If so, you'll need to `try` and `catch` inside your `checkInput` function.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to use a try/catch, you can do something like this earlier in your code:

```
function exception_handler($exception) {
    //Insert whatever you want to do when an exception is raised outside of a try/catch
} 

set_exception_handler('exception_handler');
```

Answer (score 0):

What about something like this:

```
function checkInput( $var, $emptyMessage = '' )
  if ( isset( $$var ) ) {
    return sanitize( $$var );
  } else {
    return $emptyMessage;
  }
}
```

or, similarly,

```
function checkInput( $var, $key, $emptyMessage = '' )
  if ( isset( $var[$key] ) {
    return sanitize( $var[$key] );
  } else {
    return $emptyMessage;
  }
}
```